# Get parent object within child formType event

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've created two form types as below

EmailOptInType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $_1 = $event->getData();
            $_2 = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $_3 = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();         
        });
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return 'checkbox';
}
```

And SubscribeType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'Sign up to news',
            'required' => true,
            'attr'     => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Enter your email to subscribe',
            ),
        ))
        ->add('email_opt_in', 'newsletter_opt_in', array(
            'data'  => true
        ));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    parent::configureOptions($resolver);

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Customer',
    ));
}
```

As you can see the subscribeType form includes the opt in form. Is it possible to fetch the parent forms data within the event listener of the child form EmailOptInType?

In the snippet above $_1 returns a boolean value of true which represents the checked checkbox, $_2 returns the same and $_3 returns an empty customer object.

Is it possible to get the customer object that has just been created / submitted?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the customer object an a form option when building the form (eg. in the controller):

```
$customer = $myRepository->find($customerID);
$form = $this->createForm(SubscribeType::class, $customer, ['customer' => $customer]);
```

The new SubscribeType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder
    ->add('email', 'text', array(
        'label'    => 'Sign up to news',
        'required' => true,
        'attr'     => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Enter your email to subscribe',
        ),
        'customer' => $options['customer']
    ))
    ->add('email_opt_in', 'newsletter_opt_in', array(
        'data'  => true
    ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    parent::configureOptions($resolver);

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Customer',
        'customer'   => null
    ));
}
```

And the new EmailOptInType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $customer = $options['customer'];
    $builder
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($customer) {
            //do thing with $customer
            $_1 = $event->getData();
            $_2 = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $_3 = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();         
        });
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    parent::configureOptions($resolver);

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        //[...]
        'customer'   => null
    ));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$customer` in the SubscribeType be `$options['customer']` instead?